# Does shell communicates with "ls" using pipes?

Tags: linux, shell, exec, fork, pipe

### My Understanding

When I enter the command `ls *.txt` in some shell (bash/ksh/csh/sh/whatsoever_shell),

1) the shell first expands the wild-card expression `*.txt` (e.g. a.txt, b.txt, c.txt)
2) then `fork()`s a child process
3) call `exec()` (or it's variants) with **expanded expression as command-line arguments**

Is my understanding correct? Or does this happen in other way involving pipes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You can use `strace` to figure more (esp. what happens after `execve`).

Comment: The shell doesn't use pipes unless you use a single `|` to indicate their use.  The `ls` command is a data generator; it does not read its standard input; it uses its argument list only.  It writes to its standard output, which is the same as the shell's standard output unless you do I/O redirection or pipe the data to another process.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. There is no need to use pipes since the child process can share the shell's standard I/O file descriptors.